# How do you save information in Javascript programs

Tags: javascript

As it may be obvious from my question, I'm very new to creating javascript programs. However I have made a few small programs and so I understand the basics about creating variables and getting input from the user and such. The question that I've had this entire time and have had some trouble getting a clear answer on is how do you keep that information stored after you close the program?

So for example: If the code has X = UsersName and then the user sets X to "Joe Smith" and quits the program, how can I save that data so that the next time the user opens the program the variable X is already Joe Smith?

(This is my first time using StackOverflow to ask a question so hopefully I worded that correctly and followed the proper format)

Comment: You need to store it in a permanent storage somewhere. Perhaps you want to send that value to a server which stores it in a database, or you use the browser's local storage or cookies.

Comment: Is the "program" an app or a website?  If it's a website, checkout cookies.  If it's a node/electron app, look into the `fs` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are executing JavaScript in a browser, like most of JavaScript world, not on a server (using e.g. Node.js).

In this scenario, you can

- Save a value to [`window.sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), which will be available there until the browser tab is closed (thus, probably not what you're after)
- Save a value to [`window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), which will be available there until either you or the user delete it explicitly
- Let a user download it in a form of a file (then reupload it when they want to resume), using a [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)
- Post a value to a program running on a web server (using form submission, XMLHTTPRequest, or Web Sockets), which will store it for you in a more (or less) persistent way (a file, a database, a cookie, a variable)

Comment: In theory you can embed a js vm into any program, doesn't have to be a browser or node.js.

Comment: @arboreal84: Yes, in theory, you could. It is just not very common.